# Rust: MissingOrMalformedExtensions while connecting to Nats

Tags: rust, publish-subscribe, nats.io

I want to connect to the Nats server using Rust. To do this I tried to use crate `async_nats`. [That's the documentation](https://docs.rs/async-nats/latest/async_nats/).

And here's my code:

```rust
use futures::StreamExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), async_nats::Error> {
    let client = async_nats::connect("nats://127.0.0.1:4222").await?;
    // let client = async_nats::connect("127.0.0.1:4222").await?;
    // let client = async_nats::connect("127.0.0.1").await?;
    let mut subscriber = client.subscribe("messages".into()).await?.take(10);

    for _ in 0..10 {
        client.publish("messages".into(), "data".into()).await?;
    }

    while let Some(message) = subscriber.next().await {
        println!("Received message {:?}", message);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

It looks very similar to the example but it doesn't work. Rust panics with the message

```
Error: Custom { kind: Other, error: "failed to read root certificates: MissingOrMalformedExtensions" }
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\program.exe` (exit code: 1)
```

I thought the address might be a problem, so I tried a few variants, but it didn't help.

Could you please tell me what to do to eliminate this panic?

Comment: You are trying to connect to a localhost instance of the server. Is the server instance started by you? Is it running? If so, please add that code as well for the sake of better understanding.

Comment: Yes. The server is running and it's started by `nats-server` command from Windows terminal. There's no more code

Comment: And the server does work well. I also tried to run Go script with nats connection and there weren't any problems

Comment: try running `ping 127.0.0.1:4222` does it return the pings or error?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in

https://github.com/nats-io/nats.rs/pull/788

And will be part of next release.